# Silverlight application is not showing in Firefox when setting object width and height to 100%

Tags: silverlight, firefox

I'm working on a Silverlight 4 application that seems to run fine in IE and Google Chrome, however when I try to view the application in Firefox, the application loads, but is not visible. The application is definitely loading, despite not being visible. Then I changed the height and width of Object from 100% to fixed, then its come showing in Firefox.

How can I view Silverlight applications in Firefox with maximum height and width?

Comment: Show us your code! specifically your HTML / JavaScript that embeds the Silverlight application.

Comment: <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
                width="100%" height="100%">
When changes from 100% to fixed length its is showing in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html, specify following code in CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 800px;
    min-height: 600px;
}
#silverlightControlHost {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then in `body`

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="source" value="SOURCE OF YOUR XAP"/>
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                    <!--Your other para-->
    </object>
</div>
```

Hope this works for you.